# How do you create application preferences page?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I see some application that uses the settings bundle for their app. Example: http://knol.google.com/k/usman-ismail/iphone-sdk-application-preferences#. I was wondering how to do that without it appearing at the user main settings. I see some application managed to do that. Is there any tutorial around?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you this open source application http://www.inappsettingskit.com/.

InAppSettingsKit is an open source solution to to easily add in-app settings to your iPhone apps. It uses a hybrid approach by maintaining the Settings.app pane. So the user has the choice where to change the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Either you follow the tutorial and the preferences appear in system preferences along with all the other apps, or you roll your own and open a preferences screen from within your application. You can choose either but don't ever do both, it is just confusing. To get the look and feel of the system prefs inside your app you would need to do custom UITableViewCells, which luckily is easy - see [this page of the Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1) for how to do custom cells in a UITableView loaded through one of your view controllers.
The nice part is that you can do it all from within Interface Builder if that's what you're used to.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm looking for: change the style of the table view to Grouped in the Attributes pane.